# Change the color of a JPanel with a Mouse-Click

Tags: java, colors, jpanel, mouselistener

How to change the color of a JPanel with a mouse click event?

```
public class Board extends JPanel{

    public Board() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 700));

        JPanel[][] squares = new JPanel[8][8];

        for(int i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < squares[i].length; j++) {
                squares[i][j] = new JPanel();
                add(squares[i][j]);
                squares[i][j].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click) {
                    }
                });
                if(click.getsource() == squares[i][j]) {
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.blue);
                }
                if((i+j)%2 == 0)
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                else
                    squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.black); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the if statement inside the mouseClicked method, something like this:

```
final int iCopy = i;
final int jCopy = j;
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent click) {
    if ((iCopy+jCopy)%2==0) {
        squares[iCopy][jCopy].setBackground(Color.white);
    } else {
        squares[iCopy][jCopy].setBackground(Color.black);
    }
}
```

Furthermore I would suggest always use {} in if statements. Otherwise your code could suffer from unexpected errors, since:

```
if (true)
     a += 1;
     b += 2;
```

is the same as

```
if (true) {
    a += 1;
}
b += 2;
```

which is definitely not what you expected!

Comment: I agree with the braces bit, but since `MouseAdapter` is an anonymous inner class, wouldn't `i` and `j` have to be final?

Comment: Yes true, I changed it

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please mark it as correct